# Running 'cat /dev/urandom > /dev/audio' does nothing

Tags: linux, audio, dev

I am trying to have some fun by playing some random audio using /dev/audio under Ubuntu 17.10. The command `cat /dev/urandom > /dev/audio` executes successfully but it outputs absolutely nothing to my default speaker. What is wrong here? Thanks...

UPDATE: after waiting a while, it says 'no space left on device'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was no special file `/dev/audio`. You have created a *regular* file and run out of space.

I think `/dev/audio` is an interface of [OSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Sound_System). Ubuntu uses [Pulseaudio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PulseAudio) instead.

Answer (score 2):

Has been anwsered on SO: [How to pipe /dev/urandom to linux sound output?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6466330/3022387)

Basically:

```
aplay -c 2 -f S16_LE -r 44100 /dev/random
```

Comment: FYI, `-f cd` is a shortcut for (16 bit little endian, 44100, stereo) [`-f S16_LE -c2 -r44100`] And random could (would?) block, urandom's better for this sort of non-essential randomness (crypto/LUKS output would be even better, maybe sound different though) Does it sound as bad as it... sounds like it would?